# Junit4 + Spring - creating a repeatable suit

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, test-suite

I would like to create a new unit Suit with repeatable tests for each test class in the suit, i.e. - a suit named SUIT1 with TestClass1 and TestClass2, the suite will execute TestClass1 100 times and TestClass2 50 times for example.

I have tried to do the following:

```
public class RepeatTests extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void testSuite() {

        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            suite.addTestSuite(MyTestClass.class); 
        }            

        TestResult result = new TestResult();

        suite.run(result);
    }

}
```

Problem is that the suite.run does not run my concrete tests at all..

Any ideas how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? There is a junit annotation for repeating test methods.

Comment: If you have a test that fails intermittently, You're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: Annotations for me is not approach, since I want to run suite
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm trying to do loading tests, for this I created a class with the following annotations:

```
@ RunWith (Suite.class)
@ SuiteClasses ({TestClasss1.class, Testtslass2.class, .........})
```

In the same class I try to run {TestClasss1.class, Testtslass2.class} repeatedly to loads such as {100} = TestClasss1 .....

I find code which supposedly should do it but it does not work, here's an example:
Run the entire test suite ten times

```
public static Test suite () {
     return new RepeatedTest (new TestSuite (TestClasss1.class), 10);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Code should be indented by 4 characters, and non-code should not be indented.  This will improve the code formatting and make your answer more readable.